# fieldset legend scrolling with inner table

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have a table nested in a fieldset. When the table exceeds the height of the fieldset left scrollbar is shown. The problem is that the `<legend>` element will scroll with the table and not remain fixed.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Header</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val ....<td>
    </tr>
    .......
  </table>
</fieldset>

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
    padding: 20px; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f9f9f9; 
    padding: 5px;
    height: 280px;
    max-height: 280px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

How can I prevent the `<legend>` element to scroll with the table?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different wrapper. Example:

**HTML**

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Header</legend>
    <div class="my-overflow">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Val 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Val 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Val 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Val 4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Val 5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Val 6</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.my-overflow {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

**Demo:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6vfxnjm/)